# SpriteKit and Swift or Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, spritekit, swift

As a newbie to iOS programming, I'm wondering which of these would be more conducive to the type of game I want to program. I've been tasked to program an iOS game for my company. They asked me to do this after learning I was studying some Swift on my own time.

The game will be a turn-based strategy game consisting of a map with irregular areas/polygons and player pieces that can be moved on the map. I'll need to be able to detect when a piece moves into different areas and restrict a piece to moving only a certain number of areas per turn.

Can this be accomplished in straight Swift/Spritekit?

Answer (score 0):

The graphical part can be achieved in SpriteKit very easily. To detect/restrict movement you can use Apple's Gameplay Kit, which is "generic" in the sense that it can be used with any graphic SDK, let is be SpriteKit or any other graphic library available in Swift.

You may want to check: [Path finding in Gameplay Kit](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/GameplayKit_Guide/Pathfinding.html).

Comment: Thank you for that link! Arbitrary graph looks like the solution!